# getElementById(array[x])?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to put an array in to getElementById for a loop purpose. It seems to be not working, how can I do this?

Edit: Sorry folks It says undefined.

```
    var lol=new Array( "test", "test2" );

var x = 0;
while( x == 4 ) {
    number = parseInt(document.getElementById(lol[x]).value);
    x++;
}
```

And i have inputs id named test and test2.

Comment: *It seems to be not working* : Any error messages,unexpected behavior, etc? Code would also help...

Comment: <sillyRandomGuess reason="NoCodeProvided">You have a syntax error on line 31</sillyRandomGuess>

Comment: Code snippet + error message = diagnosable problem.

Comment: @Josh your phraseology is hilariouser than mine.

Comment: getElementById() can't deal with the array. Just run through the array and do a single getElementById() on each member.

Comment: Please create a minimal example that shows the problem. Your code above will never even run the while loop since it tests for x == 4 and x is set to 0 immediately beforehand.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627255/how-to-use-array-in-getelementbyid/55301033#55301033

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your while loop only works if x==4. Change this to:

```
while(x < lol.length)
```

To loop through all the elements in the array.
Better yet, this will condense your loop:

```
var lol=new Array( "test", "test2" );
for( var x = 0; x < lol.length; x++ ) {
    number = parseInt(document.getElementById(lol[x]).value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try taking your array out of the quotes...

```
document.getElementById(lol[x]).value
```

The quotes turn it into a static string "lol[x]", when you want the value of the lol array at x index.

This replaces my earlier, less informed answer.

Hope this helps

Comment: To the quote part, it was originally not there, i just forgot to remove it after a test.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have `number = parseInt(document.getElementById("lol[x]").value);`

1. `"lol[x]"` is a string with that literal value, not the value that `lol` holds at index `x`. Use `getElementById(lol[x])`
2. `parseInt` may do unexpected things when you don't pass a radix. Use something like `parseInt(document.getElementById(lol[x]).value, 10)`

Finally, you aren't checking whether the element exists. Do something like:

```
var element = document.getElementById(lol[x]);
if (element) {
  number = parseInt(element.value, 10);
} else {
  // handle error or throw exception
}
```