# How to use array in getElementById?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am working on a project where I need to use array values in the `getElementById()` in javascript.
I tried various things, but the code isn't working.
Please help me.

I have an array of values like this:

```
 var examStateArr=["examState1","examState2","examState3","examState4","examState5","examState6","examState7"];
```

and i use it in `getElementById()` as:

```
document.getElementById(examStateArr[str1-1]).value.innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText
```

But this doesnt work.

The code works just fine when I hard code values like `document.getElementById("examState1");` but not when i use the array.

str1 is an integer that I pass from a jsp file below:

```
<%for (int j = 1; j < 8; j++) {%>
<tr>
<select  name='examCountry<%= j%>' onchange=showExamState(<%= j%>,this.value);>  
<option value="none" selected="selected">SELECT</option>
<% for (i = 0; i < countrySize; i++) {%>
<% country = (String) countryArr.get(i);%>
<option  value=<%= country%>><%= country%></option>
<% }%>
</select> 


</td>
<td id='examState<%= j%>'>
<select name='examState<%= j%>'>  
<option value='none'>Select</option>
</select>
</td>
```

Please correct my mistake.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: str1 is the iterator value in a jsp file that is passed as a parameter to the method that contains the above codes.

Comment: @Sathya Please add the code that sets `str1` so we can inspect it.

Comment: what is `.value.innerHTML`? I'm not sure if that is correct…

Comment: alert(str1) and tell us what you see

Comment: @Sathya: The reason people are suspicious is that `str1` *really* sounds like the name of a `string` variable. It will need to be an integer if you're using it to access an array by index.

Comment: <%for (int j = 1; j < 8; j++) {%>
 <td id='examCountry<%= j%>'>    
       <select  name='examCountry<%= j%>' onchange=showExamState(<%= j%>,this.value);>  
   <option value="none" selected="selected">SELECT</option>
   <% for (i = 0; i < countrySize; i++) {%>
    <% country = (String) countryArr.get(i);%>
    <option  value=<%= country%>><%= country%></option><% }%></select><td id='examState<%= j%>'><select name='examState<%= j%>'>

the <%= j%> inshowExamState is my str1

Comment: please edit your question instead of posting new code in a comment.

Comment: @Dan Tao: even if its "1" or something like that, wont the -1 type cast it back to int?

Comment: Sathya, isn't quotation necessary for attributes like `onchange`? I thought so.

Comment: `str1` is a confusing name for a variable, specially when it's an integer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var examStateArr = ["examState1", "examState2", "examState3", "examState4", "examState5", "examState6"];

for (var i = 0; i < examStateArr.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(examStateArr[i]).innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText   
}
```

**Mistake one done by you**

```
document.getElementById('').value.innerHTML   -- is wrong
document.getElementById('').innerHTML         -- is correct
```

**Edit 2**

make sure you call this function after DOM is loaded, try adding your script at the bottom

Comment: I tried removing value and wrote as you said, it still isnt working

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown us what `str1` is but it must be the problem.

For example, try:

```
document.getElementById(examStateArr[0])
```

And that should work fine.  Array access is zero-based and you have six elements, so the valid values for `[n]` are **0-5**.

It's also possible your array doesn't contain what you think it contains.  Before wondering why `docuemnt.getElementById` isn't working, you should first make sure that what you are passing in is what you expected. Use `alert`, or with Firebug `console.log` to output the value you are passing in:

```
alert(examStateArr[str1 - 1]);
alert(examStateArr[0]);
alert(examStateArr);
```

Comment: I used alerts. Everything seems to be correct. I get examState1 when I do the alert(examStateArr[str1-1]); and alert(examStateArr[0]); and all the array elements when I do alert(examStateArr).

So, if the values that are being passed are correct, is there something wrong with the document.getElementById statement?
Please help

Comment: If that is true, then are you *sure* that is actually working when you hard-code values?

Comment: I got the code working. Thank you very much for your help. There was a problem in passing str1 in the onreadystatechange method.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

if it works in the hard coded state then your problem must be in the str1-1 part of the code.

You haven't provided info on what str1 is. Whatever it is, try (str1-1) (with parens)... that might clear it up and make sure str1 is a value that represents your array index + 1 (maybe alert(str1) prior to your call to see what it actually is, rather than what you think it is).

Answer (score 0):

Yes - this is an old entry but still an up to date topic. 
So I stumbled over it as well when I was looking for a solution for the following problem: The array does not exist at the beginning (as in the example above) but will be generated dynamically via PHP inside a HTML form.

My problem was that the text lines come in with ids (or names) like for example "text[0], text[1]" and I was neither able to write **getElementById("text[0]")** neither **getElementById("text"[0])**.

It took me some time to find a solution so I wrote some example code that works for this problem. Maybe someone finds it helpful ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<script>
function getTotal(i) {
    console.log("Line clicked: " + i);
    var substr = "";
    var radio_test = "myRadio";  // !! Name may not be at the same length as "value_test" in this example
    var value_test = "myVal";
    var sum_id = document.getElementById("aim");
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var values = [];
    var status = [];

    console.log("------------------------------------------------");
    // STEP 1: Check radio elements if on/off and save their status and also their corresponding value fields
    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (all[i].id != "") {
            console.log("Find element " + all[i].id);
            substr = all[i].id.substring(0, 7);
            if (substr == radio_test) {
                console.log("=> Radio element (" + all[i].id + ") BUTTON-NO (" + all[i].value + ") STATUS (" + + all[i].checked + ")");
                if (all[i].value == 1) {
                    if (all[i].checked == true) {
                        console.log("ON");
                        status.push(1);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("OFF");
                        status.push(0);
                    }
                } 
            } else {
                substr = all[i].id.substring(0, 5);
                if (substr == value_test) {
                    console.log("Value element - NAME " + all[i].id + " VAL " + all[i].value);
                    values.push(all[i].value);
                } else
                    console.log("Another element we do not need at the moment");
            }
        }
    }

    // STEP 2: iterate through saved values and sum them up if radio button status was checked
    console.log("------------------------------------------------");
    var sum=0;
    for (i=0; i<=status.length; i++) {
        if (status[i] > 0)
            sum += parseInt(values[i]);
    }
    sum_id.value = sum;
}
</script>


<body>
<br>USE JAVASCRIPT TO SUM UP VALUES FROM ALL CHECKED LINES THAT WERE CREATED DYNAMICALLY
<br><br>
<?php 
    // Total sum of all checked lines
    echo "<div style='clear: both; padding: 5px; border-color: red; border-style: solid; margin-top: 2px;'>";
    echo "SUM <input id='aim' name='aim' type='text'>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<br><br>";

    // Create some lines dynamically (and fill them with random values for testing purpose)
    for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
        echo "<div style='clear: both; padding: 5px; border-color: black; border-style: solid; margin-top: 2px;'>";
        echo "Line $i: <input type='text' id='myVal[".$i."]' name='myVal[".$i."]' value='".random_int(1, 100)."' >";
        echo " ON <input type='radio' id='myRadio[".$i."]' name='myRadio[".$i."]' value='1' onchange='getTotal($i)'>";
        echo " OFF <input checked type='radio' id='myRadio[".$i."]' name='myRadio[".$i."]' value='2' onchange='getTotal($i)'>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```